# java hid communication dll makes jvm crash

Tags: java, dll, crash, java-native-interface, hid

I am developing an application in Java that needs to communicate with a microprocessor msp430 from TI. To communicate with the device, I use the hidDemo java code and the DLL provided (that uses the hid API C code).

My problem is that I get errors at the DLL level that crash the JVM. Problems occurs when I'm communicating with the device, and when I unplug the device.

I have tried to handle the error at the DLL level with no success. I also tried recompiling the DLL with a newer hid API version; still no luck.

The error trace generated by the JRE is the following:

> Instructions: (pc=0x74672874)
>   0x74672864:
>   [error occurred during error reporting (printing registers, top of stack, instructions near pc), id 0xc0000005]
>
> Stack: [0x4f7c0000,0x4f9c0000],  sp=0x4f9bf1c0,  free space=2044k
>   Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
>   C  0x74672874
>   C  [hidcommunicationmanager.dll+0x11db3]
>   C  [hidcommunicationmanager.dll+0x13844]
>   j  com.ti.msp430.usb.hiddemo.management.HidCommunicationManager.getSerialsForVidPid(II)[Ljava/lang/String;+0

The error is an `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x74672874, pid=3336, tid=5444`, which is like a NullPointer exception.

Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: Ask the vendor to fix the DLL so it doesn't do this.  There is no way to protect yourself from a faulty DLL in Java.

Comment: Thing is I can recompile the DLL, they provide a demo project to dialog with the microprocessor. I ave already asked the vendor about the crash ;)

Comment: It is possible the DLL can corrupt memory in a way which doesn't cause a problem in the DLL, but does cause a problem in the rest of the program.  It is also possible you are continuing to use a resource which is no longer available once the DLL has cleaned it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't allow you trap memory errors created in DLLs.

What you can do is start another process to run the DLL in.  This can be useful if say you have a 32-bit DLL and a 64-bit JVM, or a thrid party library you don't trust (JAR or DLL)

You can communicate with the JVM you start up via pipes, sockets or shared memory.  If the process dies, your main program keeps running and it can restart the process.

Comment: That could be a solution, thank you for the idea. I am still open to read some thoughts about the error

Comment: I have tried switching to the java hid api... it works under windows 7 but the api does not work in windows 8/8.1/8.1 SP1.

Comment: I meant that the java hid api I used didn't allow to connect to multiple device with the same VID and PID but I've found a fix that correct this point : http://stokersoft.com/developer/java/reliable-and-rock-solid-java-hid-usb-communication/